# Ardupilot compile error on arduino System wide configuration file is "ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-windows\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

Tags: arduino

When i try to compile ardupilot project into APM 2.X Using ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-gcc-4.8.2-window then show an error message System wide configuration file is "C:\ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-windows\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. At last i solved the problem

1. You need to download avrdude.conf file from here avrdude.conf https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lRldRMJ2dRhu3Ns5V625-gTR1KT68Jdc/view
2. Copy all af code
3. Goto your ArduPilot Arduino  folder such as C:\ArduPilot-Arduino-1.0.3-windows\hardware\tools\avr\etc
4. You will see a avrdude.conf and open in notepad ++
5. Then paste all code
6. Restart arduino ide
7. Problem solved